# How do I kill the second boss (Yelena Fedorova) in Deux Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I beat the Picus boss?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28975/how-do-i-beat-the-picus-boss)

I have a heavy rifle with about 170 ammo, no grenades, no typhoon aug.

How do I kill her? I tried just putting all the heavy rifle ammo into her but she kills me before I can unload one clip.

Comment: This question might help you: [link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28975/how-do-i-beat-the-picus-boss/29181#29181)

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I beat the second boss (Yelena Fedorova of Picus)?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/28975/21177)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I could beat her was to blow up the generators around the outside of the arena and jump around like a madman until they stop shocking me. Rinse and repeat for all four generators. Then I just had to put a few bullets in her and she went down.

Comment: Credit to some fella on /v/ by the way

Answer (score 11):

There are lockers around the room with EMP grenades and ammo/weapons in them.

You can knock her out with the EMPs (though be careful to not knock your augmentations out at the same time) and then unload all you've got while she's paralyzed. Repeat as needed.

Try to always stay on the move and don't let her get close to you. You should be able to stay moving long enough to heal up in-between the "paralyze and shoot" rounds. I also recommend saving after each round, so you don't have to restart all the way from the beginning of the fight if things go sour.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to kill her:

One is to collect the EMP grenades scattered between the generators. Throw an EMP grenade and unleash lead to kill her (as mentioned by Anna Lear).

Or the second option, which is a lot easier, is to get the EMP shielding upgrade for the Dermal Armour (if you do not have this upgrade, load an earlier save if you have one and upgrade). With this upgrade you can shoot the generators which will cause an EMP burst which will immobilise her and you will be free to shoot her, because you have the EMP shielding augmentation you will NOT be affected by the EMP burst. I found this boss the easiest of the bunch because of this augmentation.

Comment: Although if you haven't got any of the Dermal Armour upgrades then it will take 4 Praxis points to get the EMP shielding upgrade - that could involve going back too far.

Comment: You don't have to have the EMP shielding aug to use the generators, you just have to stand back.

Comment: As @Fambida says you can just "run away" from the electricity (if you check the ground, only some parts are covered with water

Answer (score 2):

There are several good ways. See the Deus Ex Wiki for a fairly comprehensive list (under [Fedorova Tactics](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Confronting_Eliza_Cassan#Fedorova_Tactics)).

I've played through the game 6 times, and now I always rely on the stun gun: the boss battles frankly annoy me, and I've found stun gun to be the simplest, most mindless way to end this one. Just shoot it enough times—about 25 times on normal difficulty I believe— and then you get to return to the "real" game. Even if I don't need the stun gun for anything else, it's worth it to carry one for this and certain other encounters.

Comment: Six times?! You know there are other games to play, right? ;)

Comment: @Alex Yeah... I'm a little obsessive about DX1 and DX3. But it's ok, I've stopped now and am being obsessive about Skyrim.

Comment: THANK YOU! Now I can get back to sneaking around w/o spending praxis points on stuff I don't need!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest fastest solution is to use the Typhoon System.  It only takes 2-3 typhoon blasts on normal difficulty and she's dead.  It took me less than 30 seconds this way...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was stuck on this for ages as I had no grenades at all. All you have to do is this: lay an emp mine near one of the 4 generators around the outer circle. Let her rush up to you with her attack near the mine, but stand back enough so you aren't killed.

In the lockers there are health kits and hypnotism sticks so make sure you have one of these to use straight away so you are not killed by the electricity from the exploded generator.

Now While she is stunned you just need to pump about 6 times with the stun gun and she dies. The trick is to make sure you aren't killed by the electricity in the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [Combat Rifle](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_rifle) with a [Target-Seeking System](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_modifications_%28DX3%29#Target-Seeking_System) mod attached very useful while fighting Deus Ex: HR bosses. Fedorova died 30s after the beginning of a fight, Namir even quicker.

Answer (score 0):

The P.E.P.S. is good for this since it stuns her for several seconds. Stun her, switch weapons and shoot her.  There's a glitch way to do it on the PC version at least. Stun her with the P.E.P.S. then run up to her and crouch.  She can't seem to attack you in that situation and she's stuck. Then you can whittle her down with the pistol or something else if you like.